# How to compare two MutableArrays and display the unmatched value in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two MutableArray values like.

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Grapes", @"Banana", nil];

NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Grapes", nil];
```

Now i have to compare that two **Mutable arrays** and display that unmatched object "Banana" into one string.

I am fresher to iOS so, anybody would send me the code for that problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggest, NSSet is probably your best bet.  However, given that *array is mutable, you could simply remove the objects from it contained in *array1

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Grapes", @"Banana", nil];
NSMutableArray *array1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Apple", @"Orange", @"Grapes", nil];

[array removeObjectsInArray:array1];
NSLog(@"array: %@", array);         //  array: ( Banana )

// if you require result as a string
NSString *objectsAsString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
NSLog(@"objects as string: %@", objectsAsString);   // objects as string: Banana
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {

    NSString *str1 = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    for(int j=0;j<[array1 count];j++)
    {

    NSString *str2 = [array1 objectAtIndex:j];
     if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
    {
    //do something which you want i.e add the values to some other array
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: run the code and found answer as Apple,Orange.

Comment: I have run it and found that Apple,Orange and grapes are matching

Comment: yes my mistake.Yes match with your output.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `NSSet` for this purpose

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"a", @"s", @"d", @"f", nil];
NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"a", @"s", nil];

NSMutableSet *notInSet1 = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set2];
[notInSet1 minusSet:set1];
NSMutableSet *notInSet2 = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:set1];
[notInSet2 minusSet:set2];

NSMutableSet *symmetricDifference = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:notInSet1];
[symmetricDifference unionSet:notInSet2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];
NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a",@"d",@"c",nil];
NSMutableArray *ary_result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *ary_resultUnmatched = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0;i<[array1 count];i++)
{
    for(int j= 0;j<[array2 count];j++)
    {
        if([[array1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[array2 objectAtIndex:j]])
        {
            [ary_result addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        } else {
            [ary_resultUnmatched addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",ary_result);//it will print a,c
NSLog(@"%@",ary_resultUnmatched);//it will print b,d
```

so in else condition you'll have your un matched values